# Playing A Sound In Python?

Tags: python-2.7, audio, for-loop, noise

After making a Morse code translator I was wondering if there was a way to play a beeping noise in python 2.7 without having a file to play it out of?
Example:

```
    for char in word:
        play sound
```

Something among those lines

Answer (score 2):

```
import winsound
Freq = 2500 # Set Frequency To 2500 Hertz
Dur = 1000 # Set Duration To 1000 ms == 1 second
winsound.Beep(Freq,Dur)
```

The winsound.Beep can be used wherever you want the Beep to occur.